# how to use get_permalink() in init hook

Tags: wordpress

I want to get current url of page in `init` hook. but they return nothing. my code is.

```
function mship_access_level() {
    global $wpdb;
    global $post;
    $slug = basename(get_permalink());
    echo get_permalink();
    exit;

}
add_action('init', 'mship_access_level');
```

Comment: "Note that when used outside The Loop on a posts page (index, archive, etc.) without the ID parameter, it will return the URL of the last post in The Loop, not the permalink for the current page." [From here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/) - Note also that these values may not be set at init and maybe you have to retreive the id from the query

Comment: Is there any alternative solution @Kaddath?

Comment: it's been a long time i haven't done this and i haven't these code parts here, try to take a look at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/

Comment: get_queried_object_id return 0

Answer (score 1):

you can try this below code for permalink

```
<?php
function mship_access_level() {
    global $wpdb;
    global $post;
    $slug = basename(get_permalink( get_the_ID()));
    echo get_permalink( get_the_ID());
    exit;

}
add_action('init', 'mship_access_level');
?>
```

Comment: you can directly put code  "<?php echo get_permalink( get_the_ID());?>" in your page loop without above function.

Comment: Wokring at page.php in theme but not working where i want :)

Comment: in which place or page?

Comment: Wokring at page.php but i want at init hook

Comment: init runs after WordPress has finished loading but before any headers are sent. Generally, this used by plugins to initialize their process.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156818/discussion-between-coder-and-shital-marakana).

Comment: I am wroking at plugin

Comment: function mship_access_level() {
 global $wpdb;
    global $post;
 $slug = get_post_field( 'post_name', get_queried_object_id());
 echo $slug ;
    exit;
 
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'mship_access_level');

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
function mship_access_level() {
    global $wpdb;
    global $post;
    $slug = basename(get_permalink($post->ID));
    echo get_permalink($post->ID);
    exit;

}
add_action('init', 'mship_access_level');
?>
```

please try this one also.

Comment: Thanks. actually $post coming empty. Means return nothing

Comment: I think you need to include "include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-config.php');" in your PHP file.

Comment: Means where you want to display.

Comment: function mship_access_level() {
 global $wpdb;
    global $post;
 $slug = get_post_field( 'post_name', get_queried_object_id());
 echo $slug ;
    exit;
 
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'mship_access_level');

Comment: I have sloved my problem by self :)